# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'circle' in Phaser JS Project. Cant use functions

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

beginner coder here.
I wanted to programm a littel game. As a test i wanted to have circle appear  random every second on the screen. If you click them they go away.

For the apperance on the screen i wanted to use a one second intervall. For that i created an gamplay function. But inside this funtion i am not able to use Phaser specific funktions. I cant create text or shapes.

My question is: Why is that? What am I not understanding? And how can i solve that instead?

Thank you for your help.

Greetings from Germany
(Sorry for type and grammer errors)

**Main gamescene**

```
   constructor(){
       super({ key: 'GameScene' })
   }

   preload(){



   }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


   create(){
       

       
       const startingMinutes = 1;     
       let time = startingMinutes * 60; //Zeit in Sekunden

       //Test Here i can still use Phaser funktions
       gameState.texttest = this.add.text(150, 250, 'This is working', { fill: '#000000', fontSize: '20px' });
       
      

       setInterval(updatecountdown, 1000);
       function updatecountdown(){
           //Countdown
           if(time > 0){
               //console.log("Time: " + time);
                const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60); //Math floor rundet
                let seconds = time % 60; 
                console.log("minuten: " + minutes);
                console.log("sekunden: " + seconds);
                time--; 
           }else{
               gameState.gameOn = false;
               
           }    
       }

       setInterval(gameplay, 1000);
       function gameplay(){

           if(gameState.gameOn === true){
       let Xvar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
       console.log(Xvar);
       let Yvar = Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*380));
       console.log(Yvar);


   
       gameState.circle1 = this.add.circle(Xvar, Yvar, 20, 0x98fb98 ); 
               
   
       gameState.circle1.setInteractive();

       
       gameState.circle1.on('pointerup', function(){
       gameState.circle1.destroy();

          
       })

       }else{
           gameState.endtext = this.add.text(150, 250, 'The End', {fill: '#000000', fontSize: '20px'});
       }

   }
       
   
   
   }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   update(){

   }




   

}
```

**Config**

```
    
};

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    backgroundColor: "#b0e0e6",
    scene: [StartScene, GameScene, EndScene]
};

gameState.gameOn = true;

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

 ``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is lost. In javascript callbacks we get as `this` current call context.
When you use setInterval, function in setInterval use as `this` not Phaser.Scene

Try to use setInterval so:

```
setInterval(gameplay.bind(this), 1000);
```